# Understand a NSDateFormatter behavior with a UIDatePicker object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I had a problem trying to set the UIDatePicker date property using this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];

NSString *GDate = @"11/07/1988";

NSDate *anyDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:GDate]; 
[picker setDate:anyDate];
```

The problem was that the date piker showed me just the year component, neither the day or the month. I've solved it changing this line:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];

// I also tried with this
// [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd'/'MM'/'YYYY"];
```

By this one:

```
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Now, I'm breaking my head trying to understand what was the problem here, but I can't reach to any consistent conclusion. Can anybody help me to understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing from `dd/MM/YYYY` to `dd/MM/yyyy` will do the trick.

According to the table presented on http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/ the only difference of YYYY and yyyy is that the former is used in "Week of Year" based calendars.